# How to connect to DB from ASP.NET Identity when there are multiple connection string including azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity

How to connect to DB from ASP.NET Identity when  there are multiple connection string including azure? ASP.NET Identity failed to connect to database as there is Azure connection string apart from SQL connection string. It throws message "A network-related or instance-specific error....".The code throwing error is given below.

```
 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

If I remove azure connection string, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For ASp.net in the web.config ,When you add a connection string, you name it.

You can access each such connection string and assign it to a different variable, passing that connection string to your data access layer.

```
<connectionStrings>

  <add name="Sales" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString= "server=myserver;database=Products;uid=<user name>;pwd=<secure password>" />

  <add name="NorthWind" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="server=.;database=NorthWind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />

</connectionStrings>
```

In Code

```
 var conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sales"].ConnectionString;
 var conn2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWind"].ConnectionString;
```

In asp.net Core , under Appsettings.json for identity, usually you have something like below

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {

    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(local);Database=Forum.Sentiment.Analyzer.Web;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

  }
}
```

**Defualtconnection** is for identity as you can see, you can add a different connection string with different name value in your Appsettings.json file.

Hope it helps.